# git tfs clone with partial history

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I'm trying to migrate a TFS repository to git, but I've run into an issue.

Looking at the history of this particular repository in TFS, it looks as though the parent was copied into a new TFS repository and then at a later time the parent was baseless-merged into it (or something similar).

When I run the "git tfs clone" command I get the error:

> git-tfs was unable to find the root changeset (ie the last common commit) between the branch '$/x' and its parent branch '$/y'...

Is it possible to limit the history with git tfs clone? I know I can use quick-clone, but that only gives me the last commit. Ideally I'd like to go back to a particular change set, or exclude the baseless merged changeset that doesn't have a common parent...

Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to clone from changeset 12345 and onwards, you can first use `quick-clone` with the flag `-c12345` or `--changeset=12345`. Then you can use `git tfs fetch` or `git tfs pull` to get the remaining history from that point on.